# error 0xe0434352 while opening visual studio 2013 ultimate ( microsoft.alm.shared.remoting.remotecontainer.dll)

Tags: visual-studio

getting this error everytime i open visual studio 2013 ultimate and after that IIS express doesnot work.

Screenshot is as below,

[image]

file is located at  - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: What happens if you just open the IDE, not a solution?

Comment: then it shows no error. It happens with every solution though

Comment: I tried everything and nothing worked. That file is located at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Final solution was to turn off "CodeLens" in settings which is just a fix.